# Removing Docker PPA from apt-get update

Tags: apt

When I run `apt-get update`, I get an error and an ignore:

```
Ign:14 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hera InRelease                         
Hit:15 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Err:17 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hera Release                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.226.234.100 443]
```

I would like to be able to remove `14` and `17` from my list. However, when I run `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`, I only see the following:

```
appcenter.list                              mc3man-ubuntu-mpv-tests-bionic.list.save
appcenter.list.save                         openvpn-aptrepo.list
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list           openvpn-aptrepo.list.save
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save      patches.list
elementary.list                             patches.list.save
elementary.list.save                        rednotebook-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list
fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-bionic.list       rednotebook-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list.save
fcitx-team-ubuntu-nightly-bionic.list.save  slack.list
google-chrome.list                          slack.list.save
google-chrome.list.save                     spotify.list
mc3man-ubuntu-mpv-tests-bionic.list         spotify.list.save
```

How can I remove these two items?

Comment: These items might be configured in one of the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, or more likely in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. To quickly find the file that configures them: `cd /etc/apt; grep -rI download.docker`.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it with the following steps:

1. Backup

   ```
   $ cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.save
   ```
2. Find the repo

   ```
   $ grep -ir "docker.com" /etc/apt/sources.list
   deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
   # deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
   ```
3. Remove invalid repo

   ```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable'
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You Can use `add-apt-repository` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu hera stable'

sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the repositories stored in `sources.list` and `sources.list.save`. To delete them, I first ran `cd /etc/apt; grep -rI download.docker` to locate the files in which the repositories were stored, then ran:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.save
```

and deleted the corresponding lines.